# Read WFS layers with PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, wfs

I need to read published WFS layers from QGIS Project file, but without success. I try using [QgsProject.entryList()](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.16/core/QgsProject.html?highlight=project#qgis.core.QgsProject.entryList) method, but only get an empty list as `[]`:

```
from qgis.core import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import QFileInfo

qgs = QgsApplication([], False)

print(QgsProject.instance().entryList("WFSLayers", "/"));

qgs.exitQgis()
```

The WFS layers are published and show up like this in QGS project file:

```xml
<WFSLayers type="QStringList">
  <value>layer1...</value>
  <value>layer2...</value>
</WFSLayers>
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you are in a standalone application according to your code, you need to load your qgs/qgz QGIS project file **before** trying to get WFS list.

At the moment, you ask to read WFS list from an empty project. So, it will always return an empty result.

```py
from qgis.core import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import QFileInfo

qgs = QgsApplication([], False)

successfull = QGsProject.instance().read('your_path/to/your/qgis/project.qgz')
if successfull:
    print(QgsProject.instance().entryList("WFSLayers", "/"));
else:
    print("Your project wasn't loaded well")

qgs.exitQgis()
```

**Edit**: the fact to load QGIS project was only part of the solution. You need to use

```py
print(QgsProject.instance().readListEntry('WFSLayers', '/'))
```

instead of

```py
print(QgsProject.instance().entryList("WFSLayers", "/"))
```

Found looking at [QGSProject API doc](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsProject.html#a6ef066a702272e84a894cd494e278351)

**Edit 2**: Illustrations about the 6 methods `readBoolEntry`, `readDoubleEntry`, `readEntry`, `readListEntry`, `subkeyList` and `readNumEntry` to access some of the XML content within your QGIS project file.

Difference between `readListEntry` and `entryList` due to xml structure in your QGIS project (see below excerpt). Explain why `QgsProject.instance().entryList("WFSLayersPrecision", "/")` works and then you need `QgsProject.instance().readListEntry('WFSLayers', '/')`.

```xml
    <WFSLayers type="QStringList">
      <value>ne_110m_populated_places_56976df7_6be4_41d8_b331_a76771b8141d</value>
    </WFSLayers>
    <WFSLayersPrecision>
      <ne_110m_admin_0_countries_d24b9f99_da2b_470c_966c_7402b525eace type="int">6</ne_110m_admin_0_countries_d24b9f99_da2b_470c_966c_7402b525eace>
      <ne_110m_populated_places_56976df7_6be4_41d8_b331_a76771b8141d type="int">6</ne_110m_populated_places_56976df7_6be4_41d8_b331_a76771b8141d>
    </WFSLayersPrecision>
```

You can also test the following:

- `QgsProject.instance().readNumEntry("WFSLayersPrecision", "/ne_110m_admin_0_countries_d24b9f99_da2b_470c_966c_7402b525eace")`,
- `QgsProject.instance().readBoolEntry(f"WMSServiceCapabilities", "/")`
- `QgsProject.instance().readDoubleEntry(f"PAL", "/CandidatesPolygonPerCM")`
- `QgsProject.instance().subkeyList('DBManager', 'savedQueries')` (need to save a SQL query in DB Manager to get results)

Comment: I still get an empty list. The project file definitely gets loaded as `print(QgsProject.instance().title())` shows me the title. But `print(QgsProject.instance().entryList("WFSLayersPrecision", "/"))` shows the list of WFS layers.

Comment: And if you open the project within QGIS and try the same line `QgsProject.instance().entryList("WFSLayersPrecision", "/")` ?

Comment: Same result: using parameter "WFSLayers" prints an empty list, but "WFSLayersPrecision" shows list of layers like `['layer1', 'layer2']`.

Comment: Updated answer and tested in QGIS and it "works". Waiting for your feedback

Comment: Great, that works! I still don't get the use of method entryList() so...

Comment: New edit with more illustrations. Up to you to play to inspect using these methods and compare with your XML structure in the qgs/qgz QGIS file